# Knockoutjs - function inside viewmodel causing undesirable recursion

Tags: serialization, recursion, knockout.js

In my Knockout view model I have a Save() function which sends a jQuery POST request. Inside this POST request is a call to `ko.toJS(this)`.

Whenever I call this Save function the browser becomes unresponsive and eventually tells me that there's too much recursion. Upon debugging (by using breakpoints), I found that when I call toJS() it appears to do some degree of cloning of the object, and in doing this cloning it calls the Save() function, which in turn calls toJS()... and there's the recursion.

Why exactly does this happen, and is there a way to avoid it without using toJSON()?

[I have another question regarding toJSON, and which explains why I don't want to use it.]

For the sake of completeness, here is my view model.

```
function vmDictionary(dict) {

    if (dict === null || dict === undefined) {
        return;
    }

    var self = this;

    // directly-assigned variables
    self.Concepts = new vmConcepts(dict.Concepts);
    self.Deleted = ko.observable(dict.Deleted);
    self.Description = ko.observable(dict.Description);
    self.IncludeInSearch = ko.observable(true);
    self.ID = ko.observable(dict.ID);
    self.Languages = ko.observableArray(dict.Languages);
    self.LastUpdate = new vmChangeRecord(dict.LastUpdate);
    self.Name = ko.observable(dict.Name);
    self.Public = ko.observable(dict.Public);

    self.TemplateName = function(observable, bindingContext) {
        return "dictionary-template";
    };

    // computed variables
    self.PublicText = ko.computed(function() {
        return sp.Utils.Localize(self.Public
            ? "Public"
            : "Private");
    });

    // exposed functions
    self.Save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: [...],
            statusCode: {
                200: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xmlHttpRequest);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
            }
        });
    };
}
```

**UPDATE:** added the entire view model (above).

Comment: Your current code still works. But because some parts are missing like `vmChangeRecord` and `vmConcepts` and `sp.Utils.Localize`. it is hard to tell what causes the recursion. I would comment out line by line the properties/functions/etc. to see which one is causing the recursion....

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something wrong, works in a little fiddle for me

http://jsfiddle.net/brN9s/

```
ViewModel = function() {
    this.someData = ko.observable("Test");
    this.dto = ko.observable();
};

ViewModel.prototype = {
    Save: function() {
        this.dto(ko.toJS(this));        
    }
};

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.Save();
```

Comment: Looks like you're right. So what can be wrong with my view model then? (I've updated the question to include the entire view model.)